# Are the tags "online-tools" and "online-applications" redundant? Merge, change, or what?

Tags: discussion, tags

Are the tags [online-tools](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-tools) and [online-applications](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-applications) redundant?

I'm a developer, and I already know from a software perspective there is a difference between a *tool* and an *application* ... so I'm not asking is there a pedantic difference in definition here.  But I think the difference isn't obvious to those not expert in software.

So **are these two tags each adding distinct value to the site, or are they being used in a redundant way?**  If they are redundant as used, which tag should be kept as the master tag during a merge?

Maybe a new tag like [online-calculator](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-calculator) would be better than [online-tool](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-tool) to tag those one-off, simple, anonymous tools that don't persist or manage any personal data but only provide calculations or estimates from data entered on the spot?  From a personal finance perspective, I think people go looking for calculators, but they don't go looking for "tools".  Then, [online-application](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-application) would used be for services that do provide personalized, advanced features.

What do you think?

Comment: Is online-application a way to apply for a service, and not a bit of software?

Comment: @MrChrister Good point - it could be.  What else, then?

Comment: Definately makes sense to merge and have online-applications. I also noticed that there is a tag "applications" thats used for 2 meanings, one as a software, the other as a form that's filled. The one related to software are not Online, but could be offline as well ... how do we treat them?

Answer (score 2):

Alrighty, I think I looked over all the questions, and I am in favor of merging the tags.  I like online-application for all of them; be it a single purpose or feature rich tool.

Having too much granularity will make it that much harder to pick the correct tag.  Perhaps online-calculator should be the only exception that proves the rule.  I feel calculator is the  way a lot of blogs describe some of these applications.